# using BASH retrieve single occurence of integer in text file

Tags: regex, bash

Have the following simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
mtp-files > test_list.txt
echo "Hello World"
ID="$(cat test_list.txt | egrep '^(File) ID: ')"

#read FILE_ID <<<"$ID"

echo $ID
```

It prints out

```
File ID: 6 File ID: 6 File ID: 6
```

But all I need is the first occurence integer value for "File ID" or 6.
What changes are needed in my script?

This is the contents of test_list.txt

```
libmtp version: 1.1.10

mtp-files: Successfully connected
Foo device detected, assigning default bug flags
Listing File Information on Device with name: Foo Device
File ID: 6
   Filename: 20161208_155851.jpg
   File size 658911 (0x00000000000A0DDF) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 6
   Filename: 20161208_155851.jpg
   File size 658911 (0x00000000000A0DDF) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
File ID: 6
   Filename: 20161208_155851.jpg
   File size 658911 (0x00000000000A0DDF) bytes
   Parent ID: 2
   Storage ID: 0x00010001
   Filetype: JPEG file
OK.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `grep` you can use this `awk` command to print first id only:

```
id=$(awk -F'[ \t]*:[ \t]*' '$1 == "File ID"{print $2; exit}' test_list.txt)

echo "$id"
6
```

- `-F'[ \t]*:[ \t]*'` sets input field separator as `:` surrounded by optional spaces.
- `$1 == "File ID"` will make sure we have our search pattern before `:`
- `exit` to exit after first print.

Comment: Or just send your original output through `head -1`.